# Facebook Graph API Event doesn't return all attending users

Tags: events, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get (using FB PHP SDK) number of users attending an open event. All good, but seems like Facebook limits number of records in response...

Example:
https://graph.facebook.com/169041749835607/attending returns 999 users although more than 1600 users attending the event.

I would really appreciate any solution on this ... how to increase / disable this limit?

Thanks

Comment: It wont allow us to see without your oauth key, but in my experience, at the very bottom of the  results will be a "next" link. Im not sure if thats there for events(ive never worked with events), but its worth a look. you can also try adding `&limit=2000` to the end of your query string

Comment: You can try here: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=169041749835607%2Fattending

and there is no 'next' link and `limit=2000` doesn't work too

Comment: Make the request in 3 calls.
`$MEcheckins = $facebook->api('/169041749835607/attending?limit=500&offset=0');`
......
`$MEcheckins = $facebook->api('/169041749835607/attending?limit=500&offset=500');`
......
`$MEcheckins = $facebook->api('/169041749835607/attending?limit=500&offset=1000');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some googling finds that ... This is a bug.

http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=13694

Answer (score 0):

Optionally you can Try Batch http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/

```
<?php
curl \
    –F 'access_token=…' \
    -F 'batch=[ \
            {"method": "GET", "relative_url": "169041749835607/attending?limit=500&offset=0"}, \
            {"method": "GET", "relative_url": "169041749835607/attending?limit=500&offset=500"}, \
            {"method": "GET", "relative_url": "169041749835607/attending?limit=500&offset=1000"}, \
            {"method": "GET", "relative_url": "169041749835607/attending?limit=500&offset=1500"} \
        ]'\
    https://graph.facebook.com
?>
```

Comment: Except for the part that it doesn't work. Even setting the limit and offset doesn't help, it's a bug in their API. Try doing that on the graph test console with his eventId and you'll see that no matter what you do you can't get more than the first 999 users. It's an open bug in their bugtrack

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't work ... Brian, thanks a lot for helping on this. Hopefully this will be resolved soon.

Comment: Glad to know, i think this issue is effecting comments to wall feed posts too.  "i am currently having issues."

Answer (score 0):

Although this is a bug with a limit of 999 users, we've found that if you repeatedly query it does return different users. We then query the results every few hours and add any new ones into our list. It tends to get around 50% of the users, which is better than just 999.

However it does require lots of API calls, so you'd think that Facebook would just fix this!